# Xcode random variable doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, variables, random

I'm using Xcode 7.3.1 and Swift, and i'm trying to set a random number between 1 and 50 like that: `variableName = random()%50`

Then i have to move an ImageView in the Y axe of that random value:
`imageviewName.center.y = imageviewName.center.y - variableName`

But it gives me the following error: "cannot convert value of type 'int' to expected argument type 'CGFloat'.

So I declared the variable like that: 
`var RandomSquirrel2 = CGFloat()` but it still doesn't wok.

How can I generate a random number in Swift?

Comment: You should surround code samples with backticks rather than double asterisks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to covert the Int to CGFloat

```
 imageviewName.center.y = imageviewName.center.y - CGFloat(variableName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast variableName to CGFloat. because random() returns an Int and not A CGFloat.

```
 imageviewName.center.y = imageviewName.center.y - CGFloat(variableName)
```